# jQuery datatable perform row reorder using specific column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable with row reorder feature to change sequence of rows using drag and drop. By default, it allows me to drag only first column to change row order. I need to change this default setting and allow a user to change sequence of rows by dragging third column.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can perform row reorder using a specific column by using the `selector` attribute and a custom class name.
Assign a custom class name to the column you want to reorder in the data table setup code:

```
...
    columns: [
        ...
        {
            data: ...
            className: 'reorder-item'
        }
    ]
```

Then just refer to it in the `rowReorder` attribute with:

```
"rowReorder": {
    "selector": '.reorder-item'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try and look here:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowReorder.selector

I managed to get it working with this settings:

```
"rowReorder": {
     "update": false,
     "selector" : "td:nth-child(4)"
}
```